# Can residues of consecutive primes repeat arbitrarily long?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Say $p_1,p_2,...p_n$ are any consecutive primes and $r_1, r_2, ... r_n$ are the residues of these, with respect to modulus $m>1$.

For all positive integer $m$, is there an arbitrarily large integer $n$ such that there exists a sequence of consecutive primes $p_1,p_2,...p_n$ where $r_1=r_2=...=r_n$?

If the answer to this question is no, this may contradict the assumption that prime numbers are uniformly distributed for all classes of residues. Because if we cannot find a sequence of consecutive primes whose remainders repeat with the desired length, this means that there are some certain upper limits. This means that consecutive primes influence each other. For example, respect to modulo 6, if the remainder is 1 happens 10 times in a row, this increases the probability that the remainder of the next prime number be 5, which is contrary to the nature of the uniform distribution.

That's why I find this research topic important.

Comment: *Probability* is the wrong word here (primes are not the result of a random process and you cannot choose a uniformly distributed prime). Even if you suitably adapted it, there would be a distinction between arbitrarily long sequences of repeated residues and equal proportions (in the limit) for the next residue.  What have you tried?

Comment: So what is a random process? How can we define randomness? A dice? No, If we knew the position of the dice, the angle, the acting force, the structure of the ground and everything else, this would no longer be random. I think the definition of randomness is not about knowing it or not. If the next dice roll is independent of the previous one, these two events are random relative to each other. We want to investigate whether consecutive primes are independent here. That's what the central limit theorem says anyway. This theorem is true only if the variables are independent.

Comment: Actually , we do not know if we COULD predict the dice outcome if we KNEW the parameters exactly. This is what we ASSUME. So , yes , a dice throw can be considered to be random. The prime numbers are not random, BUT as long as we do not know whether some number is prime it makes sense to estimate the probability that it is prime.

Comment: In most cases , we are unable to prove or disprove that some sequence contains infinite many primes , for example the Mersenne numbers. In this case , we use heuristics based on the 1/ln(n) - model. This way , we can conclude that there are probably infinite many Mersenne primes , but finite many Fermat primes (in fact we probably know them all).

Comment: But to your question : Tao proved that there are arbitary long arithmetic progressions only consisting of primes , but the proof does not show that this is still true if they have to be consecutive. In this case, I guess , the problem is open.